# SQL query to capture data with self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Example Data:

```
Id  | SwipeTime               | SwipeStatus | Invalid_message
----+-------------------------+-------------+-----------------
100 | 2018-04-07 02:45:12.290 | Invalid     | 1st Attempt
100 | 2018-04-07 02:45:14.290 | Invalid     | 2nd Attempt
100 | 2018-04-07 02:45:21.290 | Valid       | NA
100 | 2018-04-07 18:01:51.980 | Valid       | NA
101 | 2018-04-07 02:55:12.290 | Invalid     | 1st Attempt
101 | 2018-04-07 02:55:14.290 | Invalid     | 2nd Attempt
101 | 2018-04-07 18:01:51.980 | Valid       | NA
```

DDL:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
             (
                 Id INT, 
                 SwipeTime DATETIME, 
                 SwipeStatus VARCHAR(10), 
                 Invalid_message VARCHAR(20)
             );

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES (100, '2018-04-07 02:45:12.290', 'Invalid', '1st Attempt'),
       (100, '2018-04-07 02:45:14.290', 'Invalid', '2nd Attempt'),
       (100, '2018-04-07 02:45:21.290', 'Valid', 'NA'),
       (100, '2018-04-07 18:01:51.980', 'Valid', 'NA'),
       (101, '2018-04-07 02:55:12.290', 'Invalid', '1st Attempt'),
       (101, '2018-04-07 02:55:14.290', 'Invalid', '2nd Attempt'),
       (101, '2018-04-07 18:01:51.980', 'Valid', 'NA');
```

Employee 100 came to work at 2.45 and tried swiping 2 times and it didn't go through (invalid). But the third time he swiped, it worked. He went to work and swiped-out around 6.

Employee 101 came to work at 2.55, swiped two times and it did not work. He still went to work and swiped-out around 6.

I want to capture employees like 101 for a particular day. i.e., for a particular day, take the timestamp of an employee's first invalid attempt, check if within 5 minutes of his first attempt if a valid attempt was made. If not, we want his details in output.

Can this be done with a single select query? Since I am not able to write a single query, I am right now writing a procedure to do this. But I will very much like it if it can be done in a single query.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: can you elaborate on what this means: *Since I am not able to write a single query, I am right now writing a procedure to do this.*

Comment: First cut: select * from (Select ID, min(SwipeTime) from table as T1 where Invalid_message = '1st Attempt') INNER JOIN (Select ID, min(SwipeTime) from table AS t2 where Invalid_message = 'NA') on T1.ID = T2.ID where DateDiff(minute, T1.SwipeTime, T2.SwipeTime) < 300)

Comment: Expected result is " 101 | 2018-04-07 02:55:12.290 | Invalid     | 1st Attempt " ... i.e., first attempt of an employee for whom there are only invalid punches for five minutes since his first attempt

Comment: There are many problems, e.g.: check-in at 23:50, check-out at 08:10; all check-ins invalid, one valid check-out, or vice versa; You have to ensure that you properly distinguish which is the check-in/out time. There should be a column holding data if the employee is already checked in. After some invalid attempts and a specific timeout the system could assume the employee is actually present.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone it is only sample data. And I have given extra details for the ease of explanation. Currently, there is no way to distinguish between swipe in and swipe out. It is just swipes.

Comment: @scsimon I am trying to write a function... breaking into different steps. FIrst I use a cursor to get all invalid first attempt records. Then for each row, I see if there is a valid swipe between timestamp + 5 mins and -5 mins. Its work in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

Sample data:

```
declare @tbl table (Id int, SwipeTime datetime, SwipeStatus varchar(10), Invalid_message varchar(20));
insert into @tbl values
(100,'2018-04-07 02:45:12.290','Invalid','1st Attempt'),
(100,'2018-04-07 02:45:14.290','Invalid','2nd Attempt'),
(100,'2018-04-07 02:45:21.290','Valid','NA'),
(100,'2018-04-07 18:01:51.980','Valid','NA'),
(101,'2018-04-07 02:55:12.290','Invalid','1st Attempt'),
(101,'2018-04-07 02:55:14.290','Invalid','2nd Attempt'),
(101,'2018-04-07 18:01:51.980','Valid','NA');
```

T-SQL:

```
select id from @tbl t
where Invalid_message = '1st Attempt'
  and not exists(select 1 from @tbl
                 where id = t.id 
                   and SwipeStatus = 'Valid'
                   and SwipeTime between t.SwipeTime and dateadd(minute, 5, t.SwipeTime))
```

Comment: Did you mean `and not exists`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Exactly! :)

Comment: To get ids like this for one day, I should wrap this up in another select query and give where date = someday ?

Comment: @JapEvans No, just include it in `where` clause in outer query: `where Invalid_message = '1st Attempt' and SwipeTime =...`.